# Haskell >.> notation

Tags: haskell, syntax, operators, notation

In the book "The Craft of Function Programming" the symbol '>.>' joins functions together, opposite the direction of '.'.  But when I implemented it using ghci, it shows the error '>.>' out of scope. Why? Is it an old notation that is not used anymore?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably just a function defined by the book (I didn't read the book). AFAIK, `>.>` is not used anywhere. You could define it yourself:

```
(>.>) = flip (.)
```

The de-facto notation of this seems to be [`(#)`](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html?query=(a%20-%3E%20b)%20-%3E%20(b%20-%3E%20c)%20-%3E%20a%20-%3E%20c&start=0).

Since functions are <del>arrows</del> ["Control.Category"](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Category.html#v:-62--62--62-) you could also use `>>>`, e.g.

```
Prelude Control.Category> ((*2) . (+1)) 4
10
Prelude Control.Category> ((*2) <<< (+1)) 4
10
Prelude Control.Category> ((*2) >>> (+1)) 4
9
Prelude Control.Category> ((+1) >>> (*2)) 4
10
```

Comment: Thank you for this simple clear answer.  But I just don't get it, how come in the book it has this notation, it doesn't define it in the book, it uses it like a standard notation.  The >.> is even in the index of the book and on graphs of all the different Haskell operators.......

Answer (score 7):

`>.>` is not defined by default, but you could define it yourself:

```
infixl 9  >.>
(>.>) = flip (.)
```

or equivalently,

```
infixl 9  >.>
f >.> g = g . f
```

(I gave the fixity declaration based on the `infixr 9  .` in the [Prelude](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html).)

Comment: Also directly: `(f >.> g) x = g (f x)` or `(>.>) f g x = g (f x)`

Answer (score 3):

`(>.>)` doesn't appear to be defined in the standard libraries. However, there is `(>>>)` in [`Control.Category`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Category.html#v%3a-62--62--62-), which behaves the same:

```
Prelude> :m + Control.Category
Prelude Control.Category> :i (>>>)
(>>>) :: Category cat => cat a b -> cat b c -> cat a c
    -- Defined in Control.Category
infixr 1 >>>
Prelude Control.Category> let f = (* 2) >>> (+ 3)
Prelude Control.Category> f 5
13
```

Note that you can use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to figure these things out.

Furthermore, you can of course, always define such an operator yourself:

```
(>.>) :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> c)
f >.> g = g . f
```

Then you can write:

```
Main*> ((* 2) >.> (+ 3)) 5
13
```

Comment: [Hoogle isn't very helpful for finding >>> as instantiated by functions](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+%28b+-%3E+c%29+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+c%29) :(